# why isn't docker compose dns resolving to actual ip but docker run network-alias is able to resolve?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have an external network which is used by docker-compose as well as docker run. I can specify network alias in 'docker run' and it would resolve to the actual container ip, but the alias I define in docker compose doesn't resolve to actual ip. why is this? What should I do to get the alias in docker-compose resolve to actual IP?

step1: create an external network

```
docker network create --attachable -d overlay test-docker-network
```

step2: create a docker-compose which creates an alias
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'
services:
    host1:
        image: linuxserver/openssh-server
        environment:
            USER_PASSWORD: 'password'
            USER_NAME: 'user'
            PASSWORD_ACCESS: 'true' 
            SUDO_ACCESS: 'true'
        ports:
              - 2222:2222         
        networks:
            default:
                aliases:
                    - netcatalias

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: test-docker-network
```

step3: deploy stack

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml netcat
```

step4: deploy 'docker run' container in same network

```
docker run --rm --name host2 --network-alias=myalias -ti --network test-docker-network debian:buster bash
```

step5: resolve both the aliases

```
root@de1f75728a7e:~/gitprojects/docker-network-troubleshoot# docker run --rm --name host2 --network-alias=myalias -ti --network test-docker-network debian:buster bash
root@ea765c15dae8:/# ping myalias
PING myalias (10.0.8.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ea765c15dae8 (10.0.8.5): icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.022 ms
64 bytes from ea765c15dae8 (10.0.8.5): icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from ea765c15dae8 (10.0.8.5): icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.034 ms
^C
--- myalias ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 49ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.022/0.032/0.042/0.010 ms
root@ea765c15dae8:/# ping netcatalias
PING netcatalias (10.0.8.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip-10-0-8-2.ec2.internal (10.0.8.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.069 ms
64 bytes from ip-10-0-8-2.ec2.internal (10.0.8.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.068 ms
64 bytes from ip-10-0-8-2.ec2.internal (10.0.8.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.067 ms
^C
--- netcatalias ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 19ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.067/0.068/0.069/0.000 ms
root@ea765c15dae8:/#
```

step 6: get actual ip from 'network inspect'

```
root@de1f75728a7e:~/gitprojects/docker-network-troubleshoot# docker network inspect test-docker-network
[
    {
        "Name": "test-docker-network",
        "Id": "3ev3r0eo2rg81pyb2yovlmmg3",
        "Created": "2020-01-18T03:09:58.748025872Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.8.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.8.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2ba6c329d157b4a03480f978645e558bb6b46d9d5c7af3d152d943aae75c696a": {
                "Name": "netcat_host1.1.180sln82qyxp03rk8o5od5p9a",
                "EndpointID": "cf2eaf42b10083296696c3cad8e43fe392ed2374cd65fd8aa8c048a134171bd2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:08:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.8.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ea765c15dae8c1cf6f6945447897a126fdf03ae1e42d2811c95d94a9d9112f39": {
                "Name": "host2",
                "EndpointID": "67ca483fd4bd231db74a39ba8f782a95c102fc04937ef9e245bfc14100f61d11",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:08:05",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.8.5/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-test-docker-network": {
                "Name": "test-docker-network-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "0754c146c555fdf0e2d683c8ead3e0670196e201148c411f35899df226d77cc4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:08:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.8.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4106"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "08bdcafe53fb",
                "IP": "10.0.0.30"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

### Issue:

we can see that the 'docker run' alias 'myalias' correctly resolves to (10.0.8.5) from 'docker network inspect'. But 'netcatalias' resolves to (10.0.8.2). But it should actually resolved to "10.0.8.3". Why is this happening. How can resolve netcatalias to "10.0.8.3"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the ip of a virtual service load balancer that sits in front of services and distributes traffic to replicas.
If you change service routing mode to dnsrr instead vip (virtual-ip), then docker dns service will resolve names to container ips in round-robin mode.

Comment: moreover, I had to remove any exposed ports to let dnsrr work. Thanks!!